# Is it possible to check whether a string contains a dataframe cell (which is also a string)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have imported multiple XML-files. If you print a child in string format from one XML-file, then you get something like this: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms}message-driven-channel-adapter' at 0xb97260d9e8>'. I have defined a dataframe in which one cell contains the word 'message-driven-channel-adapter'. If the child (as previously described) contains a word that is present in my dataframe, then I would like to get an output (for example True or 1). Is it possible to check if a child contains a certain cell in my dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os

#defines the paths of the XML files
directory = os.getcwd() + "\\Import_XML_files"
directory2 = os.getcwd() + "\\Import_XML_files\\{}"

#importing excel file
excelname = os.getcwd() +'\\Information_Blocks_(Transformation).xlsx'
excelfile = pd.read_excel(excelname)

#define starting- and endingblocks
startingblocks = excelfile.iloc[2:,1].reset_index(drop=True)
endingblocks = excelfile.iloc[2:,4].reset_index(drop=True)

#runs through XML files
for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    #defines how to read the XML file
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, directory2.format(filename))
    tree = et.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    #reads XML file
    for child in root:
        if str(child).find(startingblocks) > 0:
            pass
```

I hope to use it within an if statement. If the child contains a cell in my dataframe then output = True or 1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, try to add example data which represents the actual data you have a problem with. It would be ideal to add an expected output as well in the form of a dataframe. This will allow people to answer more easily + to give answer in a higher quality.

Comment: Thank you! I have made a dummy Excel file. Can you tell me how to attach it to this post?